# Upgrade directly from PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.3

Tags: postgresql

Can I upgrade directly from PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.3? Or should I upgrade to 9.2 first?

I'm using Windows 8 and am planning on using `pg_ugrade();`

I tried to do this and pg_upgrade() froze on me.  No error messages and no use of CPU or RAM.

When I run pg_upgrade it briefly flashes a cmd.exe window, but only for a fraction of a second so I cannot see what it says. This might be logging me on.  I'm using runas.exe to run the cmd.exe as Aaron\postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running `pg_upgrade` from `start->run`, I suggest using an existing cmd.exe console running as the desired user. Shift-right click on the command prompt in the start menu, choose "Run as ...", and enter the desired credentials. Then run `pg_upgrade` from there. That way you'll be able to see what's going on.

Quite likely you're using extensions `pg_upgrade` doesn't know how to handle.

There is no reason to upgrade via 9.2; going 9.1 to 9.3 should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to do a dump and then restore it.  I did this and it worked fine.  It also handled the transition from postGIS 2.0 to 2.1.1.